# combine identical values in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge

I have a hard one to crack.

I have this array with emails:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 9000@domain.com 
[1] => hasseris@domain.com 
[2] => storcenter@domain.com 
[3] => osteraa@domain.com 
[4] => vejgaard@domain.com 
[5] => gistrup@domain.com 
[6] => storvorde@domain.com 
)
```

And this array with form ids:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1 
[1] => 4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2 
[2] => 148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c 
[3] => 02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0 
)
```

And with this foreach I am running through every mail in the array to create a full JSON object

```
foreach($mails_array as $key => $value) {

    foreach($formIds as $form) {

         $branchArray = array(
                   "FormIds" => [''.$form.''],
                   "Conditions" => array("sendto" => $value),
                   "From" => $date_from,
                   "To" => $date_to,
                   "Days" => ''
               );

         array_push($array, $branchArray);
    }  
}

$json = json_encode($array);
$string = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*/', '$1:', $json);
```

This creates this json that is used to call an API to return number of submissions on X forms based on a condition (sendto):

```
[{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"9000@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"9000@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"9000@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"9000@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"hasseris@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"hasseris@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"hasseris@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"hasseris@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"storcenter@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"storcenter@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"storcenter@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"storcenter@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"osteraa@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"osteraa@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"osteraa@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"osteraa@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"vejgaard@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"vejgaard@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"vejgaard@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"vejgaard@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"gistrup@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"gistrup@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"gistrup@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"gistrup@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["1a21f6b7-8025-4724-b983-14745823ede1"],Conditions:{sendto:"storvorde@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["4c8a63c0-4650-4884-b83c-70054f538ec2"],Conditions:{sendto:"storvorde@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["148c1886-6674-45f3-9665-748bb6a34f4c"],Conditions:{sendto:"storvorde@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""},{FormIds:["02fc3795-9457-4b02-91da-7d4b63eac1c0"],Conditions:{sendto:"storvorde@domain.com"},From:"2016-03-23",To:"today",Days:""}]
```

Where FormIds is a GUID of a particular form with submission. "sendto" in conditions is the mail that I want all submissions for on the particular form.

So as an example I am trying to get all submission on all 4 forms that are send to  9000@domain.com

The above json returns this, where the number is submissions on the condition:

```
{
  "arr": [
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
}
```

So that I know that the first 4 items ( 4 form ids ) in the returned JSON is for 9000@domain.com (1,0,0,0), the next 4 for hasseris@domain.com (0,0,0,0), e.t.c.

Now my problem is that I want to combine the mail array and the returned json into a simple json that I can output with the email address and the number of total submissions. The 4 forms with identical "sendto" should be combined, so that the condition with 9000@domain.com that are found on 4 forms, will be combined into a single item with the total number of submissions on the 4 forms.

Something like:

`{"landingPageData":[{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"9000@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"1"}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"hasseris@domain.com","landingPageLeads":0}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"storcenter@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"1"}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"osteraa@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"0"}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"vejgaard@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"0"}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"gistrup@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"-"}},{"landingPage":{"landingPageMail":"storvorde@domain.com","landingPageLeads":"0"}}],"totalLeads":2})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through `$mails_array` and sum subtotals using `array_sum( array_slice() )`:

```
$json = '{"arr":[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}';

$data = json_decode( $json )->arr;
$result = array( 'landingPageData'=>[], 'totalLeads'=>0 );

foreach( $mails_array as $key => $email )
{
    $subTot = array_sum( array_slice( $data,$key*count( $formIds ), count( $formIds ) ) );
    $result['landingPageData'][] = array
    (
        'landingPage' => array
        (
            'landingPageMail'  => $email,
            'landingPageLeads' => $subTot
        )

    );
    $result['totalLeads'] += $subTot;
}

$result = json_encode( $result );

echo $result;
```

will print (prettified):

```
{
    "landingPageData": [
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "9000@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "hasseris@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "storcenter@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "osteraa@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "vejgaard@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "gistrup@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "landingPage": {
                "landingPageMail": "storvorde@domain.com ",
                "landingPageLeads": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalLeads": 2
}
```

This is the core line:

```
$subTot = array_sum( array_slice( $data, $key*count( $formIds ), count( $formIds ) ) );
```

Multiplying current `mails_array` key for `$formIds` we can obtain starting `$data` key for current element, then we can extract from `$data` only values related with current email and sum them using `array_sum()`. The sum is added to a new `landingPageData` child and the `totalLeads` value is incremented by it.

---

- Read more about [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- Read more about [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)